# Excluding empty cells ("") from ascending list with Index function

Tags: excel

I have the following Excel table:

```
        A              B               C      

  1    Boris           4                *
  2    Anna            6                *
  3    Uli             5                *
  4    Inge            4                *
  5    Rudi            3                *
  6    Ulla            7                *
  7
  8
  9
  :
  : 
  99
```

*In cells C1 to C6 I am using the matrix formula:

```
={INDEX(A:A;VERGLEICH(KKLEINSTE(B$1:B$99-ZEILE($1:$99)/9^9;ZEILE(A1));B$1:B$99-ZEILE($1:$99)/9^9;0))}
```

to get the list sorted by names from the smallest to the the highest number according to column B.

The issue is now that my list has 99 rows *(as you can see in the table)* but not all of them are filled *(as you can see in row 7 - 99 in the table)*.
Therefore, the formular in cell C1 to C6 shows now the value 0 because "" (empty cell) is the smallest value in the list from B1 to B99.

How do I have to change the formular that it considers all values in column B except for the cells that are empty? *(Note: If a cell in column B has the value 0 it should be considered. Only when the cell is empty it should be excluded)*

Thanks for any help :-)

Comment: EN-US function names please.

Comment: Sorry. Here is the function in English: {VLOOKUP(A:A;MATCH(SMALL(B$1:B$99-ROW($1:$99)/9^9;ROW(A1));B$1:B$99-ROW($1:$99)/9^9;0))}

Comment: Where has VLOOKUP come from?? You posted an INDEX formula!

Comment: Sorry. I translated it wrong. Index remains Index. The answer you posted below is correct :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a condition to check for numericalness:

`=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(B$1:B$99),B$1:B$99-ROW($1:$99)/9^9),ROWS($1:1)),B$1:B$99-ROW($1:$99)/9^9,0))`

In German:

`=INDEX(A:A;VERGLEICH(KKLEINSTE(WENN(ISTZAHL(B$1:B$99);B$1:B$99-ZEILE($1:$99)/9^9);ZEILEN($1:1));B$1:B$99-ZEILE($1:$99)/9^9;0))`

I have replaced ROW (ZEILE) with ROWS (ZEILEN) as it is a more rigorous choice for SMALL's *k* parameter:

http://excelxor.com/2014/08/25/row-vs-rows-for-consecutive-integer-generation/

Regards

Comment: Danke. It works perfectly. Exactly what I needed :-)